# Linear program, show that a feasible solution is not an optimizer using convex analysis

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming

I have a linear program:
$$\max c^Tx$$
subject to
$$Bx \leq b, Ax = a, x\geq 0$$
where $x \in R^n$, $B$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $A$ is $k\times n$ matrix, and $(m+k) < n$. Rank of $[B\:A]^T$ (stacking them vertically) is $m+k$.
I have a feasible solution $\bar{x}$, such that $B\bar{x} = b$ (and $A\bar{x} = a$). It has **n** non-zero entries (so it is not a basic feasible solution).

My main task is to show that there is a 'direction for improvement' $\leftrightarrow$ $\bar{x}$ is not a solution for the program above.

My initial attempt is something along these lines

1. show that $\bar{x}$ is a vertex of a polytope defined by $A,B,a,b$
2. use a result of this kind (if it is true): there are at most $r$ (some natural number) linearly independent directions(linear functions) such that their convex combinations are maximized at a vertex of a polytope (maybe, this number is the number of linearly independent rows of a matrix that defines an $H$-polytope?) (generally, is there a max number of directions such that their convex combinations are maximized at a faces of different dimensions? I feel like there should be). Then I also know that $c$ is not a convex combination of the rows of $[B\:A]^T$, so $\bar{x}$ cannot be a maximizer.
   I understand my wording is vague here, so I attach a picture to illustrate the idea below.

On my way, I encounter some difficulties as I am new to the subject of convex analysis.

1. The book that I use is Ziegler, "Lecture on Polytopes". The definition of an $H$-polytope:

> **$H$-polyhedron** is an intersection of finitely many closed halfspaces
> in some $R^d$.

> **$H$-polytope** is a bounded $H$-polyhedron (it does not
> contain a ray ${x + ty : t \geq 0}$ for any $y \neq 0$).

2. Definition of a face:

> A linear inequality $c^Tx \leq c_0$ is **valid** for a polytope $P$ if it
> is satisfied for all points $x \in P$.

> A **face** of $P$ is any set of the
> form $F = P \cap \{x \in R^d : c^Tx = c_0\}$, where $c^Tx \leq c_0$ is
> a valid inequality for $P$.

> The **dimension** of a face is the dimension
> of its affine hull.

> The faces of dimensions $0, 1, dim(P) - 2, dim(P)
> > - 1$  are called **vertices, edges, ridges, and facets**, respectively.

I find this definition of a vertex to be difficult to apply to an $H$-characterization of a polytope. If I know that $\bar{x}$ is such that $B\bar{x} = b$, how do I come up with a valid inequality such that its intersection with the polytope is $\bar{x}$ only? I am not even sure now whether my $\bar{x}$ is a vertex.

Slightly aside: I encountered this result while studying the simplex algorithm:' basic feasible solutions are vertices'. Does it imply only one direction, that is if basic feasible, then vertex? Or is it an if and only if statement?

I would appreciate any help with any points above, but my main goal is to prove that $\bar{x}$ is not a maximizer in a sufficiently general way such that when I 'reasonably' vary the primitives $A,B,a,b$ the proof applies.

The picture: there is a polytope $P$ in $R^2$. You can see a vertex and two directions, $D1$ and $D2$, that are 'bounds' to all the linear functions that are maximized at this vertex. If the direction is not a convex combination of $D1$, $D2$ (like $D3$), then it is maximized at a different vertex.
[image: .]